# Creating a timeout method in a gtkmm app causes "void value not ignored as it ought to be" error

Tags: c++, timeout, gtk, gtkmm

I have just gotten started with gtkmm and I am trying to update a label at a predefined interval by letting a timeout method call my Update() method. However, when writing the following line in the constructor of my MainWindow class:

```
Glib::signal_timeout().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MainWindow::Update), 1000);
```

I get the following error:

> /usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/functors/slot.h:136:36: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
> return (typed_rep->functor_)();

Does anybody have a clue on how to fix this or what is the cause?

**Edit:**
Here is a minimal and reproducible example:

main.ccp

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include "MainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "com.companyname.test");

    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("prototype.glade");

    MainWindow* mainWindow = 0;
    builder->get_widget_derived("mainWindow", mainWindow);

    return app->run(*mainWindow);
}
```

MainWindow.h

```
#pragma once
#include <gtkmm.h>

class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    MainWindow(BaseObjectType* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& refGlade);
    virtual ~MainWindow();

protected:
    //Signal handlers:
    void Update();
};
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <iostream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(BaseObjectType* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& refGlade)
{
    // The following line creates "void value not ignored as it ought to be (...)" error
    Glib::signal_timeout().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MainWindow::Update), 1000);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::Update()
{
    
    std::cout << "Update" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Please port a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, what is the code behind `MainWindow::Update`?

Comment: Sorry, added it now!

Comment: Please, have a look at the doc.[Glib::SignalTimeout](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGlib_1_1SignalTimeout.html). The `signal_timeout` expects a return value of type `bool` but your handler `MainWindow::Update` is `void`.

Comment: The meaning of the return value: _If `timeout_handler()` returns `false` the handler is disconnected._ If you don't want this, just return constantly `true`. If you don't like to change the signature of `MainWindow::Update()`, you could also wrap the handler into an adapter lambda: `Glib::signal_timeout().connect(sigc::ptr_fun([this]() { Update(); return true; }), 1000);`. (I cannot check this on my side. Take it with a grain of salt.)

Comment: Yeah. I hate the binds and love the adapter lambdas. However, `Glib::signal_timeout().connect(sigc::bind_return(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MainWindow::Update), true), 1000);` should work as well, of course.

Comment: Changing the return value and returning true works, thank you! I guess I wasn't paying enough attention to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Scheff mentioned in the comments, I forgot that `MainWindow::Update` needs to return a value of type `bool`, as that is expected by `signal_timeout`. Changing the Update method to the following, fixed the issue:

```
bool MainWindow::Update()
{
    
    std::cout << "Update" << std::endl;
    
    return true;
}
```